# LINQ Querying Collection with different parameters

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dynamic

I have a list that I need to query based on about 10 different parameters that user pass to my program.

What s the best way to do it ?

ex:

```
List<Users>
```

Query params can be : username and/or user id and/or age etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is composing a dynamic query in LINQ. You could do this in two ways:

- using [dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx);
- using [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) by Joseph Albahari (recommended in this case);

Briefly, this is how to use PredicateBuilder in your case:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<User>();
if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(username))
    predicate = predicate.And(a => a.Username == username);
if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(whatever))
    predicate = predicate.And(a => a.Whatever == whatever);
/* etc. etc. */

var filteredUsers = myUsers.Where(predicate);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to build the `where` part of your Linq query dynamically - I don't recommend that via a string (see link below) because it could introduce something similar to what is known as SQL injection to LINQ i.e. change of behaviour of the LINQ query with user-supplied params in ways you don't want...

That said check this link out http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx - Scott Gu demonstrates something that comes close to what you describe including a library and some sample code...

Comment: i m querying an in memory collection. so sql injection is not a problem. and i d like to build where and group by clouses etc.

Comment: BTW: whether it is "in-memory" or not doesn't make a difference - "something similar to SQL injection" means that the user could possibly supply params to make your dynamic LINQ behave in a way you don't want...

Comment: @Yahia: You cannot SQL inject using LINQ-to-SQL, it is sanitized. SQL injection is when you explicitly concatenate strings and send them as SqlCommands to your database, which LINQ does not do.

Comment: @GFK you misread my sentence - please read the first... I NEVER say it is SQL injection, I say by compiling arbitrary strings to LINQ queries at runtime (see the link in my answer) something SIMILAR to SQL injection is introduced - because in these cases sanitazation is up to your code when building those strings !

Comment: When you're using LINQ, you explicitly call members by they name. Whatever you do with it will be checked, and LINQ only uses SqlParameter. You cannot write Where("MYTABLE.MYCOLUMN == " + userinput), it's not syntaxically correct. The only way to write it will be Where(o => o.MyColumn == userinput), which will be sanitized no matter what you do (LINQ only uses SqlParameter).

Comment: Someone else should vote this up.  It's a shame you can't vote down comments.  Yahia's link shows how you can build a dynamic query against a collection which could be used to solve your problem.  I think people in the comments section were a little quick to shoot off instead of reading the answer and trying to apply it to the solution.

Comment: @GFK - you still haven't read my answer - you say it is impossible to build a string "WHERE..." and make that a LINQ query... see the link from my answer ( http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) - there is demonstrated how to do exactly that !

Comment: Alright I stand corrected, you can actually do this with LINQ! Although I don't understand why you'd think the user was talking about this specifically. So yes indeed, using dynamic LINQ it is up to your code to do sanitizing (avoiding string concatenation or formatting using the @n style to specify parameters).

Comment: I thought the OP wanted the maximum flexibility - since without this approach he would have to code all possible "sub-conditions" and then code something to combine them... which can be alot depending on the quantity of possible "sub-conditions"... this approach makes it easier to allow for new "sub-conditions" without the need to code much to support them... except for the sanitizing part that is...

Comment: Makes sense. I never found myself in a situation where my client needs to actually write his own queries, so I did not know about that feature. I would be very suspicious about their intentions if they did though!

Comment: I had two clients who wanted this badly... and from experience I wrote in my answer above "I don't recommend"...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're talking about filtering objects based on an initially unknown number of conditions.

LINQ does not evaluate your query until you explicitly ask so by enumerating it (using foreach, ToList(), ToArray()...). And when you do that, depending on the implementation of LINQ (SQL, objects, XML, etc), the query will be optimized.

AFAIK, all implementation are able to optimize "where condition1 where condition2" into "where condition1 && condition2".

Which means you just have to add your filtering conditions one by one. For instance:

```
private List<User> FilterUsers(string username, string userid, int? minAge, int? maxAge)
{
    IEnumerable<User> query = GetUsers();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username)) query = query.Where(u => u.Username.StartsWith(username);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userid)) query = query.Where(u => u.Userid == userid);
    if (minAge != null) query = query.Where(u => u.Age >= minAge.Value);
    if (maxAge != null) query = query.Where(u => u.Age <= maxAge.Value);

    return query.ToList();
}
```

Here GetUsers() is supposed to return an IEnumerable. Can be a Table if you're using LINQ-to-SQL, ChildNodes() if you're using LINQ-to-XML. Try to enumerable the least possible **before** applying your where clauses.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is have a method with the folowing signature

```
    public void Filter(Func<Account, bool> filterExpression)
    {
        list.Where(filterExpression).ToList();
    }
```

this way you can support filtering for various scenarios on the UI.

Not breaking the encapsulation of your (I assume) repository, that's why I do the `ToList()` so no `IQueryable` is sent to the client.